# How to check if a WCF service is operational?

Tags: .net, wcf

Is there a quick and reliable way to check if a WCF service is available and accepting requests, perhaps some best practice built in method? Obviously from code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rubens already mentioned, you could create a dummy "ping" method on your service to check. This works OK and might be enough for you - **BUT**: such a ping method of course can only guarantee that your service is reachable and responsive.

In many cases, your service method will in turn depend on other resources - e.g. you need to read data from a database, parse an XML file, call out to yet another service etc. So even if *your* service is available and responsive on your Ping method doesn't at all guarantee that another call on your service will succeed.

A simple Ping method on your service typically cannot check the availability of all those dependant systems / resources. So in the end, it's really only half (or less) of the story you *can* check - just be aware of that!

To make a long story short: you can't really check for a service being available and up and running - you basically just need to call it when you need it, and be prepared to handle bad things, like timeouts, network link broken etc. Good defensive programming practices apply even more so in the connected, service-oriented world!

Comment: Wondering if a Windows service hosting multiple WCF services could keep running if any of the latter crashes (or will the entire Windows service crash). In other words, do I need to ping all WCF services to make sure they are all running or a single ping to anyone of them is good enough?

Answer (score 5):

You can to implement an empty method and call it every time you want.

You could to try this article too: [How to: Use Health Monitoring to Instrument a WCF Service for Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949048.aspx)

Comment: The link provided gives ideas for how to implement monitoring on the service host side. It doesn't help with regards to how to detect whether the service is operational from a service client. At least that is how I understand the question.